# Serialized file, deserialize file in arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, serialization, deserialization

I want to read the serialized file from a different class and populate an ArrayList with the object values. Anyone can help me?

```java
    import java.io.*; 
    public class CreateEmployeeSer{

    public static void main(String args[])  {
        try
        {
           ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream("employee.ser"));
           output.writeObject(new Employee(101, "Brown", 6500, M, 28));
           output.writeObject(new Employee(201, "Johnson", 6300, F, 28));
           output.writeObject(new Employee(301, "Belt", 5500, F, 30));
           output.writeObject(new Employee(401, "Bulb", 7400, M, 40));
           output.writeObject(new Employee(501, "Goodness", 6400, F, 30));
           output.writeObject(new Employee(601, "Filter", 4900, F, 22));
           output.writeObject(new Employee(701, "Porto", 5000, M, 19));

           output.close();
        }//end try       
        catch(IOException fnfe)
        {
            System.out.println(fnfe);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }//end main
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :-

```
class demo{
    
   public static void main(String[] args){
       try{
             ArrayList<Employee> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
             ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("employee.ser"));
             for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
                    Employee employee = (Employee)in.readObject();
                    arrayList.add(employee);
             }
             in.close();
          }
          catch(Exception e){
                System.out.print(e);
          }
     }
}
```